# Count string occurance and assign output parts variables

Tags: php, linux

Good Day everyone
Having a bit of a "Head Bang"on this. Im trying to find a way to search through files for a certain string. I know how to do it in linux by using a simple grep -c, but i'm unable to assign varaibles to the output. For example I want the file name as $var1 and the count as $var2, the reason for this is I will be using the data in a chart. I'm not to fixed on using linux commands, if there is any better way to do so I am open to using it. I would appreciate any info or direction of where to go and read up. My code:

```
 <?php
   $output = shell_exec ( "grep -c 'detected Tag 10055' *.txt" )
 ?>
```

This would the give me the file path and count as ../../public/130512.txt:100.
Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0):

Use the another method in PHP to capture the output of the external program

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

For example

```
$command = 'ls -ltr';
$response = exec ( $command, $output , $return );

print_r($output);
print_r($return);
```

The variable output array will contain your execution output, from that you can take the result.

The $response contains your last line of external program's output
$output contains the array of all output line by line
$return is the return value of your external program

Comment: @Vijay, Sorry seems I forgot to add im quite new to php, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Vijay, thanks will play around with this. Thanks for the info, still seems to output the full ../../public/130512.txt:100 and not 130512.txt seperate from :100.

Comment: If you know the file name then you can directly specify the filename in the grep command or use -h to suppress the file name. Otherwise from php you can explode and use the result

Comment: @Vijay - There will be more than one file to search the string occurance in. Will have a look at explode, thanks.